# The evaluation method of ucf-101 with lstm

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, lstm, conv-neural-network

I am interested in classifying the human-activity in UCF-101 by combining CNN and LSTM.
In UCF-101, 101 classes have multiple videos and each video has one target.
As far as I've research, videos in UCF-101 is pre-processed by framerate.
Numerous frames of the video are captured at a time-step.
Depending on the pre-processing several frames from one video have each class.
And in many papers, they verifying the accuracy of the model with the classification accuracy of each class(confusion matrix).

The final result is the accuracy of the class for a single video or the accuracy of the class for multiple pre-processed frames??